# What is the purpose of the out queue in RedisMQ?

Tags: redis, servicestack

In the Re-usability use-case project with RedisMQ there is a SMessageService which has the following handler.

```
SMessageService :Service{

    public object Any(EmailMessage request)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Db.InsertAll(Email.Process(request));
        return new SMessageResponse { TimeTakenMs = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds };
    }...
}
```

When the services returns, it puts the message in the mq:SMessageResponse.inq list.

My questions is if I return null instead of new SMessageResponse{...}, a message is put in the mq:EmailMessage.outq list, what is the reason for this?

Also, if I don't want to return a response at all, how would I do this or is this bad practice in the area of messaging?. In other words, I always need to have a log of what has happened.